# Compactions in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I was trying to make a configuration change in `cassandra-env.sh` file.

For the change to be effective I have to bounce my cassandra nodes. But the nodes I want to bounce are running compactions.

So what will happen to these pending tasks if I bounce my nodes when the compactions are in progress?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said before, compactions will stop when you bounce the nodes. But it will pick up once you start the nodes again. No warn on that. If you have really long compactions ongoing, you might want to wait for those to finish.

`nodetool compactionstats -H` is your friend to check the current status and expected ETA of the current compactions.

If you want your nodes to startup faster, flush `nodetool flush`, drain `nodetool drain` and then stop the node. (This way you clear the commitlog).

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple: your pending compaction will be failed for the dependent nodes. For `development` or `test` environment, you may do whatever you want but for production environment we prefer, complete your all pending compaction tasks and then go for the changes.

If you are in a hurry then go for [Nodetool Stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50712602/compactions-in-cassandra), it'll stop your compaction process then go for the changes.